# IE8 Object Expected JQuery .ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, object-expected

I have the following function that is called in the head tag.

```
Page::IncludeJavascriptFile('js/packages.js');
Page::AddHeadElement('
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            pollClientTable('.TriplecastConfig::get('transfer_polling_period')*1000 .', true);
        });
    </script>
');
```

pollClientTable is defined in packages.js which is before the function call.

pollClientTable function:

```
var pollClientTableTimer = null;
var pollClientTableTimerPoll = null;
function pollClientTable(poll, async) {
clearTimeout(pollClientTableTimer);
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax_requests/getClientPackages.php",
    async: async,
    timeout: poll,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#packagesForm').empty();
        $('#packagesForm').append(data);
    }
});
    pollClientTableTimerPoll = poll;
    pollClientTableTimer = setTimeout(function(){pollClientTable(poll, true);}, poll);
}
```

The functions work in any other browser bar IE8. Any ideas why?

Comment: What is the version of JQuery that you using in you project?

Comment: I Think its 1.8.7 but thats only a hunch not sure and no one knows

Comment: What? You are a rogrammer or not? Please use Firebug or Inspect element or see the script of code for knows which version you using? 
And in every version there is a problem with IE and remove or change name function.
Look on http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/

Comment: Appologies, didnt realise you could do that ...l Turns out we are using 1.9.1